# Colonizing Mars: Is research being done to find the most radiation-tolerant plant species?

Tags: mutations

Due to Elon Musk's stated objectives to colonize and live on Mars in his lifetime, is there research occurring to determine what plants would be the most hardy to survive in the extreme environmental conditions of the planet?

Direct surface growth appears to be impossible due to strong ultraviolet rays reaching the planet's surface due to the lack of an ozone layer, and also the direct unimpeded cosmic ray bombardment leads to surface radioactivity, due to the lack of geomagnetic field protection.

But are there any research studies being done to try to determine what plants if any would be most tolerant of partial or minimal shielding from these otherwise life-ending and mutation-forming environmental conditions?

It is well known that initially all colonization support materials are going to have to be transported to the red planet from Earth. It will be a long time before the initial colony would be capable of mining, sorting, processing, and producing anything useful from surface materials already on the planet.

If it would be possible to design a reduced-shielding Mars greenhouse roof material that is lighter and thinner than one that provides the full filtering needed to produce safe Earth-like solar irradiance for common food crops, then it would be possible to build larger and more expansive in-ground / underground greenhouses for hardy slow-growing but radiation tolerant plants, to help support slow-but-steady oxygen production for the more fragile parts of the rest of the Mars survival mission.

Comment: There is a Space Exploration SE

Comment: I was not aware of that. Should I vote to delete and then repost there, or can it be moved by a moderator?

Comment: this question have been asked over at https://space.stackexchange.com/ before and you can find some good links there.https://space.stackexchange.com/search?q=plants+on+mars

Comment: No need to flag your own post – just click on the 'Delete' button (grey text at the bottom of your question).